# How to address fields in Pig Latin after loading

Tags: apache-pig

Have a large file with a lot of columns file which I am loading like

```
A = LOAD '/path/to/file' USING PigStorage(',');

B = FOREACH A GENERATE $0 AS name, $1 as address, $2.. ;
C = FOREACH B FILTER BY (name is NOT NULL);
```

I get an error that projected field [name] does not exist? I dont want to address columns by doing $0, $1 and all that . How can I give them some identifiers ?

Answer (score 1):

That pig script doesnt run for me - but changing  to this :

```
A = LOAD '/path/to/file' USING PigStorage(',');
B = FOREACH A GENERATE $0 AS name, $1 as address, $2 as another;
C = FILTER B BY (name is NOT NULL);
```

does work.

Comment: OOps sorry I mistyped the question. But doesnt it say that [name] does not exist.

Comment: no, it works fine for me - my test csv has a variable number of fields - I load and assign the first two fields to name and address as you do and filter name.

Comment: And did you use .. to address rest of the number of fields .

Comment: I did not load the rest of the fields of the csv, as that was not what your question was about. Pig allows you to only load the fields you are interested in, the rest are ignored.

Comment: But if you use .. operator, then somehow you are not able to address fields which are named using 'AS' .

Comment: ok - I see that. if you do a describe for B , the schema is unknown.

Comment: Which makes sense, because otherwise you would have a partial schema. Pig either know the schema of all the fields or not at all.

Answer (score 0):

Nested FOREACH will be a better option

```
B=FOREACH A {
   filtered_rec =  FILTER A BY (name is not null);
   GENERATE filtered_rec;
}
```